# Display letters above the player head in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like to make it possible to see the text from `textlabel` above the player's head when they first join the team called `RedTeam` with the team-color `Really Red`, only if they have the correct group rank (Captain). How can I achieve this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
    local Players = game:GetService("Players")
    local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")
    
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
        player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
            game.Teams.Redteam.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
                script.BillboardGui.Frame.Visible = true
                print(player.Name .. " joined the game!")
                local groupId = "Captain"
                local guiClone = script.BillboardGui:Clone()
                guiClone.Parent = character.Head
    
                local textlabel = guiClone.Frame.TextLabel
                local groupRank = player:GetRoleInGroup(groupId)
                textlabel.Text = groupRank 
            end)
        end)
    end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The groupid passed through :GetRoleInGroup() must be a numerical id tied to the group, not a string. The user's rank as a string is returned through this function.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")

-- Playerjoined is unnecessary; the same thing is being done when a player enters the team.
Teams.Redteam.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        -- Merely set the frame to be visible in explorer. Parented inside a script, it is not rendered, therefore the next line is not needed.
        --script.BillboardGui.Frame.Visible = true
        print(player.Name .. " joined the game!")
        
        local groupId = 123456789 -- Your group's id
        local requiredRank = "Captain"
        local groupRank = player:GetRoleInGroup(groupId)
        
        if groupRank == requiredRank then
            local guiClone = script.BillboardGui:Clone()
            local textlabel = guiClone.Frame.TextLabel
            
            textlabel.Text = requiredRank
            
            guiClone.Parent = character:FindFirstChild("Head")
        end
    end)
end)
```